# Using CreateControlCollection() from within a WebMethod

Tags: vb.net, webmethod, controlcollection

my code calls a WebMethod.  Within that WebMethod I  have the need to create a new control collection.  In VB I would normally write:

```
Dim cc As System.Web.UI.ControlCollection = CreateControlCollection()
```

But because I'm inside a WebMethod, I get the error :

```
Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.
```

Any suggestions please ?
Thanks folks !

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies you are trying to access an instance-level member or method from a shared method. If you want to access an instance-level method or member from a shared method, first you must create an instance using the new operator and you can access its public members and methods from there on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but yeah - I understood what the error message meant.
The problem is, within a web method - you cannot use the [new] command - it returns
`Dim cc As New System.Web.UI.ControlCollection
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'NEW' accepts this number of arguments`